# Issues in Spinner setselection(position) with Sqlite Database android

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner, selection, android-spinner

Hello friend i want to set selection() in spinner as per SQlite databse id so my cod eis as below

```
ArrayList<ParserCategory>mArrayListParserCategories = new ArrayList<ParserCategory>();
    mArrayListParserCategories = mDatabaseConnectionAPI.getCategoryData(mStrinGetTrMode);
    mSpinnerAdapterData = new SpinnerAdapterData(mArrayListParserCategories);
    mSpinnerCate.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapterData);
    int id= mSpinnerCate.getIndexFromElement(mSpinnerAdapterData,mStringGetCantname);
```

**DatabaseConnectionAPI.java**

```
public ArrayList<ParserCategory> getCategoryData(String type) {

    ArrayList<ParserCategory> mGetCategoryList = new ArrayList<ParserCategory>();
    try {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Category_Master where cat_type like "+ "'"+type+"'";
        Cursor mCursorCategory = Query(sqlQuery);
        if (mCursorCategory != null) {
            mCursorCategory.moveToFirst();
            while (!mCursorCategory.isAfterLast()) {

                ParserCategory mParserCategory = new ParserCategory();
                mParserCategory
                .setCatId(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("cat_id")));
                mParserCategory
                .setCatName(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("cat_name")));
                mParserCategory
                .setCatType(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("cat_type")));
                mParserCategory
                .setCatMode(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("cat_mode")));
                mGetCategoryList.add(mParserCategory);
                mCursorCategory.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        mCursorCategory.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mGetCategoryList;
}
```

**SpinnerAdapterData.java**

```
    public class SpinnerAdapterData extends ArrayAdapter<ParserCategory> {
    ArrayList<ParserCategory> mArrayList;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Activity mActivity;

    public SpinnerAdapterData(ArrayList<ParserCategory> list) {
        super( IncomeUpdateActivity.this, R.layout.custom_spin_layout, list);
        this.mArrayList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
         convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_spin_layout, null);
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        mTextView.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getCatName());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**getIndexFromElement Function**

```
public int getIndexFromElement(ArrayAdapter<ParserCategory> adapter, String element) { 
      for(int  i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) { 
            if(adapter.getItem(i).equals(element)) { 

                  return i; 
            } 
      } 


      return 0; 
}
```

When i run above code it retruns id always 0 any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter contains `ParserCategory` objects, and you are comparing them to `String` parameter, which is always false. You probably want something like this (assuming the element should match the CatName field):

```
if (((ParserCategory)adapter.getItem(i)).getCatName().equals(element))
```

Another solution is overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` in ParserCategory class.